# Fun Vacation to Maine

Tags: logical-deduction

Some college friends decided to take a vacation in Maine together. They each had to chip in \$90 for the weeks' lodgings.  They tried to convince three more people to go with them, to reduce the cost per person to \$22.50, but they were unsuccessful. How many friends actually want?

Comment: interesting puzzle - I have to ask is the text formatting with italics etc. deliberate? - if so then we will treat it as a clue - if not do you need help formatting your question.

Comment: looks like this is a textbook-style math question. maybe it belongs over at math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that:

> $9$ people went.

Math:

> $90x=y$  ($x$ people times $\$90$) = cost of trip 
>  $(x+3) \times 67.5 = y$ 
>  $67.5x + 202.5 = 90x$ 
>  $22.5x = 202.5$ 
>  $x = 9$

Comment: looks good, you beat me to it... :-)

Comment: I think you've got this inverted. The OP says "reduce the cost ... *to* $22.50," not "reduce the cost ... *by* $22.50." That makes the answer ten minus the answer you came up with.

Comment: It originally said "reduce the cost by".  (If you check the edit, you can kind of see it)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the number of friends who went to Maine is:

> 1 (can we really still say 'friends' went to maine??)

The maths:

> Let C be the total cost of the vacation
>  Let X be the number of people attending the vacation
>  From the question, we have the following equations:
>  C/X = 90
>  C/X+3 = 22.5
>  We can solve this set of simultaneous equations as follows:
>  C = 90X
>  90X/X+3 = 22.5
>  90X = 22.5X + 67.5
>  (90-22.5)X = 67.5
>  X = 67.5/67.5
>  X = 1